# Deleting rows from excel with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to run the following code in Python.
What I'm expecting is that the code will read in the Excel file, delete rows 1 and 2, then print the first few rows of data to the console:

```
import pandas as pd

path = 'C:\\Temp\\'  
filename = 'datafile1.xlsx' 
df = pd.read_excel(path + filename, sheet_name=1) 
df = df.drop([0,1])   #delete the first two rows
print(df.head())
```

I can't seem to upload the excel file here, so I've taken a screen shot of it here:
[Excel file][1]

Here are the results that display in the console:

```
runfile('C:/Temp/getdata.py', wdir='C:/Temp')
           Title Here Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5
NaN               NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
sort order       Type  reference     cliref     couref      haref    contref
2                 FMN        NaN          b          5        dfs      dfs-5
3                 ACB        NaN          c          6        dfs      dfs-6
3                 ACB        NaN          d          7       fasf     fasf-7
```

The first two rows are still present:
"Sort Order" should appear first, "Title Here" should not be showing at all.

What do I need to change?
Thanks in advance for your help.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHdDh.png

Comment: Why aren't you using [`skiprows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)?

Comment: you expect the rows to disappear from the excel file ? or just the data frame?

Comment: Why aren't you using skiprows? – roganjosh
That solution seems to be working well, thanks

You expect the rows to disappear from the excel file ? or just the data frame? – KZiovas

Just the dataframe - If I understand right, I think that is what this is doing? I plan to clean the dataframe, then export the results back to csv at a later point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `skiprows` by skipping 2 rows:

```
df = pd.read_excel(path + filename, sheet_name=1, skiprows=2)
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to produce the result I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, if I understand the OP correctly because the question is not clear, you can not remove them because they are read in as headers. Try to read the excel file with no headers like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel(path + filename, sheet_name=1, header=None)
```

and then drop the rows

Comment: Thanks, this kind of works, but I think my header row is now 0,1,2,3 etc rather than the headers that I have in the excel file? skiprows seems to be working best for what I need. Thanks for the tip though, much appreciated 

runfile('C:/Temp/getdata.py', wdir='C:/Temp')
            0     1          2       3       4      5        6
2  sort order  Type  reference  cliref  couref  haref  contref
3           1   FUN        NaN       a       4    fds    fds-4
......
6           3   ACB        NaN       d       7   fasf   fasf-7

Comment: no problem! Even though it is not the solution you wanted please give an upvote if you think it was usefull

Comment: I tried to upvote, but apparently I need a reputation of 15 to do that - I only have a reputation of 3 as I'm a newbie :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using header and index column

For an excel file
[image]
it could look like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", header = [0,1],index_col=[0], skiprows = [1])
```

it produces the output

```
  Title here
        type reference cliref couref haref  contref
1        fun       NaN      a      4   fds    fds-4
2        fmn       NaN      b      5   dfs    dfs-5
3        acb       NaN      c      6   dfs    dfs-6
3        acb       NaN      d      7  fasf   fasf-7
5        dis       NaN      e      8   dfd    dfd-8
4        exb       NaN      f      9   fds    fds-9
4        exb       NaN      g     10   adf   adf-10
4        exb       NaN      h     11  asdf  asdf-11
4        exb       NaN      i     12    df    df-12
```

Comment: I modified your code to include my file path as follows:
df = pd.read_excel(path + filename, sheet_name=1, header = [0,1] , index_col=[0])

I get this error message:
ParserError: Passed header=[0,1] are too many rows for this multi_index of columns

Comment: try pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", header = [0,1],index_col=[0], skiprows = [1])

Comment: I updated the answer, note it is multi index, ie to access, for example, haref you would type df[('Title here', 'haref')]